# VueJS Sibling Component Reload Challenges

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get a component to reload after a sibling is updated. For instance, when I make a selection in the first component, I want the second component to "refresh" to account for the newly selected "state" data:

```
<c-select
  dataEndpoint="/states.json"
  errorMessage="Some error message..."
  id="state"
  message="Some message"
  v-model="form.state"
  :v="$v.form.state" />
```

Has the following dependency, so to speak:

```
<c-select 
  :dataEndpoint="`/${form.state}.json`"
  errorMessage="Some other error message..."
  id="county"
  message="This field uses a local data source and **is required**"
  v-model="form.county"
  :v="$v.form.county" />
```

Once a state is selected or changed, I need to "dynamically" reload the appropriate endpoint to show the counties for that state in a second component. Right now, the only way I can make this work is with a `v-if="form.state` hack. But, if a user attempts to change the state again, the changes do not take effect in the "county" component. I would appreciate any help or advice on how to best solve this issue.

Here is a [link to my vue codebase in Code Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l75287nmm)

Comment: Try moving `form.state` to computed property or method. Should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is the result:

[image]

`mounted` is executed only ONCE, so after `dataEndpoint` has changed NO UPDATE action performed, that's why you should add `watch` to your `c-list` component and check if the entry has changed - update drop-down list:

```
watch: {
    dataEndpoint() {
      this.fetchAndSetJsonEndpoint();
    }
  },
```

Here is a working version of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/64mj19r6zw

Comment: Thank you for your help. I truly appreciate it.